# Romanian virtual keyboard layout with special characters for Android

Tags: android, google-apps, language, virtual-keyboard

I have acquired a rather basic tablet for the simple purpose of writing. I am using different languages, amongst which Romanian.

[Gboard has a Romanian language but the keyboards under that are not Romanian-specific, they are generic qwerty or azerty without the special characters](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233541/add-standard-romanian-keyboard-with-diacritics-to-gboard) ăîțșâ.  (Looking at other languages I notice that  not even French has a specific keyboard in Gboard, it's just a generic AZERTY,  but that some, like Turkish, do have specific keyboards with special characters.) The same is true about other mainstream keyboards like Microsoft SwiftKey. These characters are available as many special characters by long pressing a i s t, but I am looking for a keyboard with the characters on top, like on layouts available on computers or even [for Android external keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/185124/romanian-layout-for-physical-keyboard-is-absent/233465#233465).

It is a Romanian-specific QWERTY layout, in Linux it is called "Romanian standard" or Romanian standard cedilla"

[image]

There are a lot of apps on the store claiming to provide that keyboard, but they are fake or otherwise misleading or full of ads. I am looking for a serious app, well supported.

I do have an answer myself, and I'm in part posting in order to provide an answer, but on the other hand I'm expecting better ones.

Comment: Fyi - you sshould also have a look at https://android.stackexchange.com/ forum if you have not already done so.

Comment: AnySoftKeyboard is an excellent ***open-source*** virtual keyboard for Android that I have personally used. I'm not seeing Romanian in their list of 42 currently supported languages, but perhaps one of the existing languages has the needed characters, or you could be the one to add support for Romanian!  See: https://anysoftkeyboard.github.io/languages/ and https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard

Comment: @ZZ -  software requests are offtopic there I guess.  But I should test that..

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - I have tested that, it doesn't offer more than Gboard etc. The fact it is open source means nothing here. Romanian is present in Gboard, but the Romanian-specific layout is not under that language, all layouts are non-language specific, I mean with no special characters on top. As said in question, the characters are available by long press. I will also post an image.

Comment: [Add standard Romanian keyboard with diacritics to Gboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233541/161921)

Answer (score 0):

[Flesky](https://www.fleksy.com/) has *some* special characters on its "QWERTY (Romanian)" language setting, but âÂ is missing.

[image]

[Multiling O Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kl.ime.oh) is a bit complicated, with an interface that has many options. By going to Settings - Layouts, one is directed to [this page](http://hanwriting.blogspot.com/2015/08/direct-links-to-all-language-plugins.html?m=1)  where Romanian can be selected, leading to [this Romanian Keyboard Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.plugin.ro) on the web store.

It provides all the characters, no matter the somewhat advanced/odd interface.

[image]